# Silverlight 5 Double-click in a ListBox

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I have seen lots of examples of using the new Silverlight 5 double-click feature. However, none of them have shown how to capture double-click in a ListBox.

Anyone have any examples/tips on how to set this up?

I am using MVVM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this by creating a custom trigger that keeps a tally of the number of mouse clicks. Once `args.ClickCount == 2` via the the parameter `MouseButtonEventArgs args` being true, you can invoke the logic you need:

```
public class DoubleClickTrigger : TriggerBase<FrameworkElement>
```

Within the `<DataTemplate>` for the `ListBox` you could use the custom event trigger created above. See the following post for more in-depth information:

[Double Click trigger for Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996871/double-click-trigger-for-silverlight)