# Double Click trigger for Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, blend-sdk

**Related:** ["Cleanest single click + double click handling in Silverlight?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1274378/1001985/)

---

What is the simplest way to make a double-click trigger some action in XAML?

I'm trying to do something like this, closing a popup when the user double-clicks a ListBox item:

```
<Popup x:Name="popup">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Color="{Binding Color}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="DoubleClick">
                            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=popup}"
                                                     PropertyName="IsOpen" Value="False" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Popup>
```

The problem with this above is that, of course, there is no "DoubleClick" event.  So I need to replace the `EventTrigger` with a double-click trigger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a custom double-click trigger by inheriting `TriggerBase<T>` and attaching a listener to the "MouseLeftButtonDown" event.  Check the "MouseButtonEventArgs.ClickCount" property to check for the double-click:

```
public class DoubleClickTrigger : TriggerBase<FrameworkElement>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.AddHandler(FrameworkElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnClick), true);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.RemoveHandler(FrameworkElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnClick));
    }

    private void OnClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.ClickCount == 1)
            return;
        if (args.ClickCount == 2)
            InvokeActions(null);
    }
}
```

With this, the XAML in the OP should work by replacing the EventTrigger with the above `DoubleClickTrigger`.

Comment: +1 I dig this man thanks, might also point out anything ClickCount wasn't introduced until SL5

Comment: @ChrisW. thanks, I should have mentioned that.  In the question I linked above, people are having to time the interval to check for a double-click, but SL5 makes it easier with ClickCount.  Also, it appears that WP8 supports ClickCount (but not WP7, presumably).